How can I build a Rust library with debug symbols with a build ID?
I have the following release profile in my Cargo.toml:
[profile.release]
opt-level = "z"
strip = true
debug = true
split-debuginfo = "packed"
lto = true

When I build with cargo build --release on Linux x86_64, the library itself has a build ID, but the debug .dwp file does not:
$ file target/release/*.so*
target/release/libli.so:     ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=61ddc8fe0e6fe664564de7504fde1aa9141acb2e, stripped
target/release/libli.so.dwp: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

I have cargo 1.80.1 and 1.80.1.
How should I update my release profile so that the .dwp debug file contains a build ID?
